# Should the namespace identifier put in front every parameter?

Tags: c++

For example,

Matrix.h

```
namespace Matrix
{
    class mat
    {
    public:
        mat(int row, int col);
        const mat &operator=(const mat &rhs);
    }
}
```

Matrix.cpp

```
Matrix::mat::mat(int row, int col)
{  // implementation here  }

const Matrix::mat &Matrix::mat::operator=(const mat &rhs)
{  // implementation here  }
```

Above codes will compile without any problem. The question is, should I put the namespace identifier in front the parameters, like `const mat operator=(const Matrix::mat &rhs);` and
`const Matrix::mat Matrix::mat::operator=(const Matrix::mat &rhs)`? What is the convention way to do this and why it will compile without adding the identifiers?

Comment: You can either do that, or use `namespace Matrix{...}` around these methods. I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your code IN namespace

Matrix.cpp

```
namespace Matrix {

  mat::mat(int row, int col)
  {  // implementation here  }

  mat& mat::operator=(const mat &rhs)
  {  // implementation here  }

} //namespace Matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a style preference which is totally personal. I have worked with a number of people over the past decade who preferred that style. The majority of people seem to prefer other ways, though.

If you are working on a project that uses this convention then be consistent and do the same. Otherwise do what you like. But bear in mind that using a style described in your question likely won't help you find people who share the same style preference.

What people usually do is put the definition inside the same namespace as declarion, as @billz has showed in his example. Another way is to put `using namespace Matrix;` at the top of the `Matrix.cpp` file (and not in the header) before providing a class definition, though this is somewhat less explicit and funky way of doing this, IMHO.

Hope this helps. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Just to mitigate potential issues:  `using namespace Matrix;` should only be done at the top of the `Matrix.cpp`.  **Never** place a `using namespace` declaration in a header file.

Comment: @ZacHowland: That's right. There are some cases though when you might want to do that, but not in a global scope of course. My style preference - no `using namespace` in my code at all :)